# Printing result of custom model in Python using ModelBuilder and ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, python-2.7, python-script-tool, parameters

I have a custom model (called TOOLNAME) in a custom toolbox developed in Model Builder on ArcGIS 10.1 Desktop. The model takes two input parameters (`SingleFDI_D` and `dayindex`) and outputs a Derived parameter called "`MaxFDI_DateTime`" which is data of String type.

[image]

The model runs well within the ModelBuilder on ArcGIS Desktop. It returns the result `MaxFDI_DateTeime: 22/11/2017 12:00:00 AM` as below.

[image]

I will need to run the model in Python.

How do I get the output of MaxFDI_DateTime out of the tool execution in Python?

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(TOOL_DIR)
# The custom model should return a String, how to retrieve it here?
model_result = arcpy.{TOOLNAME}_{TOOLBOX_ALIAS}(SingleFDI_D, str(day))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet `model_result` is a [Result object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm).

Without testing I think the string you are after can be printed from that using:

```
print(model_result.getOutput(0))
```

or

```
print(model_result[0])
```

Comment: Thanks! If the code snippet has multiple (i) output params, we could potentially use model_result.getOutput(i-1)?

Comment: That's what I would try.